# Есть какая-нибудь замена sort в ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, сортировка, arraylist

Нужно отсортировать `ArrayList`, но Android Studio пишет

> "Call requires API level 24 (current min is 21): java.util.ArrayList#sort"

есть какая-нибудь замена или можно не сортировку, а просто элементы в случайном порядке по `ArrayList` раскидать?

Comment: [`java.util.Collections`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html) - там много полезного и сортировка тоже.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [`Collections.sort(list);`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List%3CT%3E)) — сортирует коллекцию, используя компаратор
- [`Collections.shuffle(list);`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List%3C?%3E)) — перемешивает коллекцию в случайном порядке